# Connecting to Domino Server from Vaadin java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lotus/domino/local/Session

Tags: java, vaadin, lotus-domino

I've built a Vaadin 8 application that connects to my Domino server.  I'm using Eclipse Oxygen with Tomcat 9 and a local install of Lotus Notes 9.x

When I run the application from Eclipse it runs fine.  Connects to domino and pulls my data.

I installed a production Tomcat server and deployed my application to that Tomcat server.  When I run the application and try to connect to domino I get the NoClassDefFoundError  lotus/domino/local/Session

I've got the NCOS.jar file in the lib path.  I tried using Notes.jar and installing a local Notes client and added the path to the notes install to the path.  When I do that I get the error Unsatisfied Link Error

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the notes jar's perhaps require some native libraries which are not on your productive server?
PS: A full stack trace perhaps helps finding the issue

Comment: Interestingly enough this is the first error I am getting
C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\oncall\WEB-INF\classes\star.object.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)

I suspect that could be the issue yet the file is in the location it is looking for it.  Any idea why it couldn't find it?

Comment: In the latter case where you are trying to get notes.jar working, since you installed a Notes client rather than a Domino server, it's possible that you have 64-bit Tomcat but 32-bit Notes DLLs. They can't work with each other.

Comment: So uninstalled the 64 bit Java and Tomcat.  Installed all 32 bit versions.  Thank you Richard.  Still getting Unsatisfied Link Error.

Comment: Turns out it was the 32 vs 64 bit.  I'm still having issues accessing my .properties file but when I hard coded my values everything connected on the back end.  Thank you so much!!!